# Add a pair to a std::map that has a const value

Tags: c++, constant-expression

I need to update this map to include one more key-pair. The map is `const std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>> children_`.

The `const` seems to block any method that is tried. Attempted code:

1. `children_[]`
2. `children_.insert()`
3. `children_ = /* newly created map */`

Why can I not override the existing map?

**Example:**

```
  current_node->children_['c'] = std::make_shared<TrieNode>(TrieNode());
```

**Getting errors**:

```
No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>>'clang(ovl_no_viable_subscript)
stl_map.h(512, 7): Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>>', but method is not marked const
stl_map.h(492, 7): Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::map<char, std::shared_ptr<const TrieNode>>', but method is not marked const
```

Comment: can you use `emplace`?

Comment: Your map doesn't have a const value. Its value is a shared_ptr to const. That's very different, and shouldn't be a problem. Show the actual code you've tried as well as the compile error you get.

Comment: Added code example and error. Tried emplace and insert.

Comment: According to the error message, the map itself is `const` so obviously you can't add values to it. Post a [mre].

Comment: *The map itself is const*, presumably the map  is a class member and the method containing the code is a const method.